# Undefined control sequence while using bib file for References

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, errors, miktex, texmaker

I'm using TexMaker, if it helps. I also have TeXnicCenter and TexWorks.

The tex file is the following:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}  
\begin{document}  
(...)  
\bibliographystyle{unrst}  
\bibliography{C:\filelocation\bibfile}  
\end{document}
```

This produces an 'Undefined control sequence' error... How could I fix it?

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: You can't use backslashes in the path name, as TeX sees them as macros. It is usually better to put the bibliography file in a place where BibTeX will find it by itself, and just use `\bibliography{bibfile}`. Note that on Windows even slashes work, as far as BibTeX is concerned.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. However, I don't know where I could put the file so BibTex find it by itself. I'll google it.

Comment: There is an environment variable `BIBINPUTS` that can specify paths where BibTeX should look for bib files.

Comment: @mapf see my answer about `BIBINPUTS`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Given that you've found the source of your error, I'll try to explain you where to put your bibliography file so to let BibTeX find your bibliography.

1. Put your `bibfile.bib` in the same directory where your `.tex` file is.
2. Leave your `bibfile.bib` in the directory "C:\filelocation" and call BibTeX in this way (assuming that your `.tex` file is `test.tex`)

   > bibtex --include-directory="C:/filelocation" test

In both cases change the offending line:

```
\bibliography{C:\filelocation\bibfile}
```

to

```
\bibliography{bibfile}
```

Note that the second way **works with MiKTeX only** (it doesn't with TeX Live).

Unfortunately, using the `BIBINPUTS` environmental variable to set extra paths where to search for `.bib` files (as suggested by @mapf) works bad with MiKTeX, so it is better don't follow that way. This because MiKTeX has a strange manner to manage variables like `BIBINPUTS`. In fact, the search order is:

> 1. The current directory.
> 2. The directory specified with `--include-directory` command-line switch.
> 3. Directories in the MiKTeX root folder
> 4. Directories specified in `BIBINPUTS` variable

In your case, with Complete MiKTeX installed, if you run `kpsewhich bibdata.bib` you will get:

> C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/bibtex/bib/mslapa/bibdata.bib

(or something similar) which is the file used by MiKTeX even if you set:

```
BIBINPUTS=.;C:/filelocation;
```

---

### ADDENDUM

Just for completeness, I forgot to mention this obvious case:

1. Put your `bibfile.bib` in a subdirectory of your `.tex` file, let's say `biblio`.

In this case, BibTeX finds it if you write

```
\bibliography{biblio/bibfile}
```

Comment: I've already tried putting the bibTeX file into the current directory of my TeX file. It worked perfectly. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: I don't use MikTeX, so what goes wrong with BIBINPUTS there?

Comment: @mafp You can see it from my answer. MiKTeX uses `C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/bibtex/bib/mslapa/bibdata.bib` instead of `C:/filelocation/bibdata.bib` if you don't specify `--include-directory="C:/filelocation"` in the command line. This is the (strange) way MiKTeX behaves in regards of `BIBINPUTS`.

Answer (score 4):

As @mafp says in the comment, you cannot use `\` in the path name. Instead, change `\` to `/` should solve the problem.