# Where should I put bibfile.bib to use it directly in \bibliography{bibfile}?

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, paths

I usually have to include my bibliography file by specifying the whole path:

```
\bibliography{path/to/bib/file/bibfile}
```

Where can I put the file `bibfile.bib` so that I can include those bibliography entries using only the line `\bibliography{bibfile}`?

Comment: On GNU/Linux (and related) with TeX Live: `~/texmf/bibtex/bib`

Comment: As this is already covered in an answer to a previous question by @karlkoeller, I'm minded to close this as a dupe.

Comment: @jon, not always we have that folder. I'm using TeXlive 2011 and I don't have it.

Comment: @jon The OP is using MiKTeX on Windows. See his [previous question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/120402/27635).

Answer (score 8):

This is actually distribution-dependent. [karlkoeller's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/120426/21591) covers the MikTeX case. For TeXLive it is a little bit different. Here, `bibtex` will search the paths given in the environment variable `BIBINPUTS` for `.bib` files, and the paths in `BSTINPUTS` for bibliography style files (.bst). In case you don't provide a `BIBINPUTS` variable, BibTex will use a system default that is defined in texmf.cnf. (You can find texmf.cnf via `kpsewhich texmf.cnf`)

In my case I find

```
BIBINPUTS = .;$TEXMF/bibtex/bib//
```

there, which means that the current directory (`.` is the short-hand for that) is searched first, then the directories under `$TEXMF/bibtex/bib`. `$TEXMF` is your system's TEXMF tree, i.e., the place where TeXLive has been installed.

In contrast to MikTeX's bibtex, in TeXLive we don't have a `--include-directory` command line switch, which is a pity.

So many people will put their `.bib` files in the same directory as their `.tex` files, and BibTeX will find them without any further configuration. As I reuse my bibliography databases quite often, I collect them in a central place (`${HOME}/bib` usually) and set `BIBINPUTS` accordingly in `.bashrc`.

Comment: What if I want to add a completely different directory, say in my User folder (something like C:\\User\my_name\a_folder)? I guess I need to convert this path to a more unix-like one, but still it does not seem to work.